# Python 3 - append to a private EMPTY list

Tags: python, list, instance, python-3.3

Why does this structure in a private class-variable append his data to a previous instance?

```
class garden:
    __flower = []

    def __init__(self, flower):
        self.__flower.append(flower)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__flower)


g1 = garden([1,2,3,4])
print(g1)
g2 = garden([5,6,7,8])
print(g1)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Compare to the "string behaviour" look really diffrent to me - why this:

```
class garden:
    __flower = ""

    def __init__(self, flower):
        self.__flower = flower

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__flower)


g1 = garden("dsf")
print(g1)

g2 = garden("asdf")
print(g2)
print(g1)enter code here
```

Output:

```
dsf
asdf
dsf
```

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because variables declared in a `class` but *outside* any `def` are *class attributes*, shared by all instances of that class.

```
class Garden(object):

    class_flower_attribute = []

    def __init__(self, flower):
        self.instance_flower_attribute = [flower]
```

Comment: isn't  `class_flower_attribute` going to face the same problems [as described here](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#default-parameter-values)

Comment: Jop, thats what I searched for :-) Thx

Comment: @DaanTimmer no, it is a class attribute not a mutable default parameter value. Whereas the latter is usually an accident, the former is usually on purpose!